# Best way to create a temp table with same columns and type as a permanent table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a temp table with same columns and type as a permanent table. What is the best way to do it? (The Permanent table has over 100 columns)

i.e.

Usually I create table like this.

```
DECLARE  #TT TABLE(              
  member_id INT,    
  reason varchar(1),    
  record_status varchar(1) ,    
  record_type varchar(1)    
 )
```

But is there any way to do it without mentioning the column names and type, but mention the name of another table with the required columns?

Comment: thats not a temp table, thats a table variable.

Comment: @nathangonzalez- yes it is..updating the question.. I believe the answers apply to both.. please enlighten if not

Comment: @Ananth, table variables have to be explicitly declared, so the way it was originally is about as good as it gets.  temp tables can be created using a `select into` statement, which is more future proof and less time consuming than handtyping the ddl

Comment: @fyr, i fail to see how this is a duplicate of that question.  he doesn't even mention `select into` in his question, and most of the answer there is irrelevant.

Comment: @fyr.. I dont need the data..Just need one table with same schema

Answer (score 163, accepted):

```
select top 0 *
into #mytemptable
from myrealtable
```

Comment: +1 Was going with a "where 0=1", but your solution is faster.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Just out of interest, how did you measure that? I did some crude testing on my own and see no difference between the two.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Didn't do a deeper analysis but I saw a minor difference, running an older SQL server and top 0 seems to not access tables or indexes at all, while where 0=1 seems to access the primary key index. Not sure how big the difference time wise though, don't have a huge table to test with. Also, this sounds rather implementation dependent, so may be different in newer versions.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Can confirm 2008R2 seems to (time wise) take the same time for both with a large table (50M+ rows, PK only). Not a DB where I have any trace permissions though, so can't see if it plans identically.

Comment: Note: if `myrealtable` has any computed columns, they will be inserted into the temp table as real columns, which is generally undesirable.

Comment: I get SQL Error 8101 when trying this, because my origin table has a identity pk. How can I prevent it?

Comment: @MateusFelipe you'll likely have to select each column individually and then cast the identity column to just a normal int/bigint.

Answer (score 16):

I realize this question is extremely old, but for anyone looking for a solution specific to PostgreSQL, it's:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table LIMIT 0;
```

Note, the temp table will be put into a schema like pg_temp_3.

This will create a temporary table that will have all of the columns (without indexes) and without the data, however depending on your needs, you may want to then delete the primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE pg_temp_3.tmp_table DROP COLUMN primary_key;
```

If the original table doesn't have any data in it to begin with, you can leave off the "LIMIT 0".

Comment: For Postgres it's also a bit neater to do `CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table (LIKE original_table)` if you just want an exact copy of the structure with no data.

Comment: can you create an unlogged temp table or is that done by default with postgres?

Answer (score 9):

This is a MySQL-specific answer, not sure where else it works --

You can create an empty table having the same column definitions with:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_foo LIKE foo;
```

And you can create a populated copy of an existing table with:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_foo SELECT * FROM foo;
```

And the following works in postgres; unfortunately the different RDBMS's don't seem very consistent here:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_foo AS SELECT * FROM foo;
```

Answer (score 8):

Sortest one...

```
select top 0 * into #temptable from mytable
```

**Note : This creates an empty copy of temp, But it doesn't create a primary key**

Comment: this will also insert all data.

Comment: @nathangonzalez : i tried and the solution worked perfectly.. Just the table was created without any data

Comment: I've been having issues with this and auto incrementing ids.

When inserting into the temporary table the ID's are reset.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * into #temptable from tablename where 1<>1
```

Comment: if i'm not mistaken, the downfall here is that sql server has to evaluate 1<>1 for each row in the table.

Comment: @nathangonzalez: No, it hasn't. The optimizer is not that dumb.

Comment: @ypercube, then i guess i am mistaken.  i see it does a constant scan.  suppose i should have checked.

Answer (score 0):

**Clone Temporary Table Structure to New Physical Table in SQL Server**

[image]

we will see how to Clone Temporary Table Structure to New Physical Table in SQL Server.This is applicable for both Azure SQL db and on-premises.

***Demo SQL Script***

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempTable;

SELECT 1 AS ID,'Arul' AS Names
INTO
#TempTable;

SELECT * FROM #TempTable;
```

***METHOD 1***

```
SELECT * INTO TempTable1 FROM #TempTable WHERE 1=0;

EXEC SP_HELP TempTable1;
```

[image]

***METHOD 2***

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO TempTable1 FROM #TempTable;

EXEC SP_HELP TempTable1;
```

[image]