# Best way to create In-Memory table with same columns and type as a permanent table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My question is the same as this old one, but creating an in-memory table instead of a temp table:
[Best way to create a temp table with same columns and type as a permanent table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206433/best-way-to-create-a-temp-table-with-same-columns-and-type-as-a-permanent-table)

I have tried this, because it is the accepted answer in the old question, but it does not work (I think it is because the table variable must be declared):

```
select top 0 *
into @mymemorytable
from myrealtable
```

It throws that exception:

> Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 2 Incorrect syntax near '@memorytable'.

I have also tried to declare the table variable as `declare @mymemorytable as table();`, but of course it throws an exception:

> Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Is there any way to achieve it without declaring the table variable detailing all the fields and types? Which is the best way to get it?

Thank you

Comment: What happens when you try to SQL you posted? Do you have more details other than just "it does not work"? Does it give an error message? Did you try `WHERE 1=0`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes, it throws a syntax error (I am nearly sure it is because variable is not declared). I update the question. Same error with `WHERE 1=0`.  Thank you

Comment: You can't do this. Table variables must have a definite structure at declaration time. You can create a temp table this way, but not a variable (whether in-memory or otherwise). To do this you'd have to generate the entire statement dynamically, including the variable declaration. That's a lot of effort for what's probably better done either client-side, or just with an actual table. [Memory-optimized tempdb](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database#memory-optimized-tempdb-metadata) is another option to consider, if you have SQL Server 2019.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I had hope that somehow the in-memory table was "autocreated", just like a temp one is.

Comment: No. This is a crucial difference between table variables and regular tables. The in-memory status isn't relevant (except that `INTO` can only create on-disk heap tables and nothing else).

Answer (score 0):

I think the most you can do is something like this:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.MyTableType
    AS TABLE  
    (  
            Column1  int
        ,   Column2  int
    )
GO 

DECLARE @InMemTable dbo.MyTableType
;  

INSERT INTO @InMemTable VALUES (1,1), (1,2), (2,3)
;  
SELECT * from @InMemTable
;
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't see why this is better than `DECLARE @InMemTable as table`, because this way I have to declare the variable and detail every column too. Can you explain a little bit more, please? Thank you

Comment: I didn't say is better. it is just an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There are no columns in your declaration of @table.
You need to enter the structure of "myrealtable".

If you want to skip that part you need to use a temporary table instad of a table value parameter.

Ie

```
SELECT *
INTO #table
FROM myrealtable
```

Alos, it's considered good practise to drop the temporary table once your done with it.
It's also considered bad practise to use SELECT * instead of listing all columns :)

Comment: If you use #table you are creating a temp table (like in the old question). What I ask is to create a variable table (`@table as table`). Thank you

Comment: Then you need to specify all columns,